# Strange precision in unpacking a numpy array with *

Tags: python, numpy

I am working with the numpy array `x = np.arange (2.5,7.0,0.01)`. If I give the commands `print(x)` and `print(*x)` I obtain different results. I know that *x unpack the numpy array, but I would expect the same values. For example, the last value printed by `print(x)` is 6.99, while the analogous one is 6.989999999999904. Why this discrepancy?

Comment: It most likely has to do with numpy print options vs. float print option.

Comment: Same as `print(list(x))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you print a specific value, you get the same result. But while printing the whole array the values are truncated by the `print()` function

```
x = np.arange (2.5, 7.0, 0.01)
print(x[3])
```

the value is: `2.5299999999999994`
when compared to

```
print(*x)
```

values : `2.5 2.51 2.5199999999999996 2.5299999999999994 ...`